# ruby thread not wait

Tags: ruby, multithreading

In ruby I want to execute some local command which will generate a file,then I want to read the contents of the file,and modify it.

However I always get null.

This is the code:

```
exec "java -jar xx.jar --output main.txt";
content=IO.read('main.txt');
content="somethinkg:"+content;
File.open('main.txt','w') do |f|
  f.puts content
end
```

the main.txt is generated,however I can not modify the content.

Then I think it maybe caused by the thread,when the `main.txt` is being read,the java command is not complete,so the content is empty.

Then I tried this:

```
t=Thread.new do
  exec "java -jar xx.jar --output main.txt";
end
t.join
content=IO.read('main.txt');
puts content
content="somethinkg:"+content;
File.open('main.txt','w') do |f|
  f.puts content
end
```

However nothing changed,I can not still get the content.

What is the problem?

Comment: try it without `exec` no code after exec is every executed since exec swap the memory try system or backtick operator

Comment: @Viren that sounds right - you should add it as an answer, I was way off base :)

Comment: @Viren:use `system("java ...")` instead?

Comment: @Viren:I am not at company now,I will have a try tomorrow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem over here is the exec command If you check the ruby documentation on exec 
over [here](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Kernel.html#method-i-exec)

the code after exec never execute

so

```
t=Thread.new do
  exec "java -jar xx.jar --output main.txt";
end
```

So your code never run anything after this

Try with system or backtick command

something like this

```
t=Thread.new do
  system "java -jar xx.jar --output main.txt";
end
t.join
content=IO.read('main.txt');
puts content
content="somethinkg:"+content;
File.open('main.txt','w') do |f|
  f.puts content
end
```

Hope it help

Comment: Why bother with the thread?  System blocks until the child process exits.

Comment: @Catnapper I know that But I not sure is that the only part of code or there is something else hence I never suggest it since he tag the question in `multithread`

Comment: I'd tell that java program to use stdout instead of a file, and use Open3.popen3 (or similar) to directly read stdout.  It's less code, and doesn't involve the file system.